# Intelij ultimate and spring boot giving me errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, build-dependencies

I am pretty new to programming and this is my first attempt at using IntelliJ IDE both ultimate and community. The errors are impending my smooth studies. Can someone please tell what is wrong in plain English?

[image: SpringApplication]

[image: Maven POM]

This is  my first attempt at programming and I was running a Spring Boot application (HelloWorld) in IntelliJ Ultimate and Community, but haven't been able to scale past these errors.

Comment: First try to rerun maven import with force update, as suggested. And second I would strongly advise against *starting to learn* with spring, it's a huge framework. You are trying to run, before you know how to walk.

Comment: this has nothing to do with intellij, nor with springboot. for all we know, you didn't even add the necessary dependencies. If you are "pretty new to programming", immediately jumping in advanced frameworks might not be the best way to go

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

As of this post, [`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.2.4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/3.2.4) is a little over a week old. So if you are using some internal network you might be having issues pulling it down.

I would remove the `<relativePath/>` from the `<parent>` and rebuild from the command line first. Just specify the group, artifact, and version.

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</parent>
```

---

If you are having module resolution errors, you can try two things:

- Open the [Maven tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.3/maven-projects-tool-window.html) in the sidebar and click the "Reload All Maven Projects" (refresh icon) button.

  - If you don't have the Maven perspective enabled, you may need to re-import your project as a Maven project. Also, you can toggle the tool with: View > Tool Windows > Maven.
- If that didn't work, try navigating to the File menu and selecting [Invalidate Caches...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html) and clicking the restart button.

**Note:** You should try building the project from the command line as an alternative every so often as a sanity measure. Especially if you add/remove Maven dependencies.